# Flow believes value is null even after wrapping in an if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

`this.collapsible` is a React Ref with type `?HTMLElement`. I'm trying to set a `style` like so:

```
this.collapsible.style.height = ...
```

And, despite wrapping the above in an `if (this.collapsible && this.collapsible.style)`, it seems that flow still believes that `this.collapsible.style` could be null.

```
Cannot get this.collapsible.style because property style is missing in null or undefined [1].

      97│
      98│   componentDidMount() {
      99│     if (this.collapsible && this.collapsible.style) {
     100│       this.collapsible.style.height = getInitialHeight(this.props);{
        :
 [1] 148│   collapsible: ?HTMLElement;
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: What happens if you are more explicit? Like `this.collpasible != null`?

Comment: @MinusFour Good question. I tried with `if (this.collapsible != null && this.collapsible.style != null)` and the result is the same

Comment: can you try aliasing a variable to test? `const elemDefinitelyExists: HTMLElement = this.collapsible` inside the `if (this.collapsible)` check?

Comment: I think `getInitialHeight` is invalidating your check. I would move that outside the `if` block and put it inside a variable. Then assign that results of that variable inside the `if` to your `this.collapsible.style.height`

Comment: @JohnRuddell that works!

Comment: So then the issue is it still believes that `collapsible` is optional. [**you could cast if needs be**](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/)

Comment: @JohnRuddell thank you, please feel free to formalize your answer in a post below

Comment: Well I dont feel like thats a true answer lol. You should be able to infer the type with an if check like you are doing (this is why I prefer typescript). Can you try using a cast? You can also just answer with what you finally do and i'll be happy to upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @John Ruddell pointed out, aliasing a variable works.

```
if (this.collapsible) {
  const collapsible: HTMLElement = this.collapsible;
  collapsible.style.height = getInitialHeight(this.props);
```

I wasn't able to find a nice way to cast the type without having to create a new variable.